# lost data in webusercontrol asp.net after postback

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, webusercontrol

in asp.net
i create one web user control and create it online(dynamic load)

when i use it static,micro soft asp.net support it and hold all data after post back ,hold all data

but when i create by code and set id

lost data after any post back, reload data and set grids and drop down list is needed.

drop down list lost data and selected index.

how i can use asp.net dynamic web user control  as static mode
i need hold all data

i use update panel and create my controls into a panel that placed in update panel

thanks

Comment: Put your code in `if(!IsPostback){//Code goes here}`

Comment: for fill drop down lists and grids need load data in post backs else all controls will be empty